# Не могу подключиться к серверу по ip

Tags: java, spring-boot

Я запускаю spring boot приложение на своем ПК, оно стартует нормально, но подключиться к нему по ip я не могу, порты на роутере открыты, в брандмауре тоже открыто, если в application.properties укажу server.addres=<мой ip>, то при старте приложение фейлится с ошибкой, что порт, на котором стартует приложение, занят. Что нужно сделать, что-бы к нему могли подключаться по моему внешнему ip через интернет?

Comment: вам роутер выдает внутренний айпи. чтобы к вам подключиться (с учетом, что роутеры, фаерволы и прочее действительно не блокируют запросы), в самом роутере нужно посмотреть ваш реальный айпи адрес(с вероятностью 99% он динамический, так что по окончанию сессии изменится и все опять перестанет работать), после чего настроить в роутере переадресацию внешних запрососв, выполненных на определенный порт, на тот внутренний айпи, к которому подлючен ваш комп. внутренний айпи выглядит примерно так: 192.168...

Answer (score 0):

У Вас есть следующие возможные трудности:

1. Когда Вы запустили приложение на своём компьютере (сервере), надо проверить, к какому сетевому интерфейсу оно биндится. Если это магический 0.0.0.0 - это означает, что приложение должно отвечать на запросы к любому принадлежащему серверу интерфейсу.
2. На сервере может быть заботливый брандамауэр, или файервол, котрый заботливо блокирует входящие соединения. Нужно проковырять в нём дырку, чтобы запросы "снаружи" проходили "вовнутрь"
3. Дальше у Вас идёт роутер. Любой сервис типа myip.ru скажет Вам внешний адрес. Вы можете настроить на роутере переадресацию портов, чтобы с внешнего интрфейса порт пробрасывался на внутренний. В случае большинства провайдеров этого будет достаточно, чтобы кто угодно в интернете мог приконнектиться к работающему у вас на сервере приложению, за исключеним:
4. в экзотческих случаях, например, при использовании сотовых операторов, у Вас есть еще NAT провайдера. То есть, Вашему роутеру выдается ip не из интернета, а из внутреней локальной стети провайдера. А потом Ваши запросы маршрутизируются в интернет, а ответы - обрато.
5. Ну, и как вишенка на торте - провайдеры могут по умолчанию блокировать некотрые порты. Проверить это можно либо в лично кабинете, либо путём эксперимента.

Это всё - не приговор, я уже много лет держу домашний сервер, пользуясь провайдером Билайн, (и пресекая все их попытки перевести меня на более новый тариф, котрый как раз закроет все возможности по расшариванию портов). Если Вы скажете Вашу ОС и провайдера - возможно, я смогу подсказать, с какими из перечисленных трудностей Вы столкнётесь?